I want to choose the top 60% of animals in my study. 72% of the selection weight is due to random factors, while 28% is due to height.
I want to choose the top 60% of animals in my study. 72% of the selection weight is due to random factors, while 28% is due to their height (both random factors and height are in z scores and normal distribution).
How much will the height of the animals in the study be inflated relative to the original sample pool?
I have been debating this hypothetical question with my friends, but none of us are math experts (we our biologists :). Would be grateful if someone tells us how we can estimate the shift in heights. Thanks!
